# YouTube PHP API v3 - Upload Fails when including recordingDetails - Invalid value for Double

Tags: php, youtube

I'm trying to add `recordingDetails` to an upload call. It seems to work fine on small test files, but with larger files I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 400: global, Invalid value for Double: )

With the help of some debugging code I was able to find out this error happens when executing this line of code: `$status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);`

If i comment out `$video->setRecordingDetails($recordingDetails);` the same file uploads fine.

I'm new to the API, and I can't seem to find anything related to this error online. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

My code is below:

```
        # Get file info for upload
        $resource=get_resource_data($ref);
        $alternative=-1;
        $ext=$resource["file_extension"];

        $videoPath=get_resource_path($ref,true,"",false,$ext,-1,1,false,"",$alternative);

        // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
        // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
        // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
        // video category.
        $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
        $snippet->setTitle($video_title);
        $snippet->setDescription($video_description);
        $snippet->setTags(array($video_keywords));

        $snippet->setCategoryId($video_category);


        // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
        // "private" and "unlisted".
        $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
        $status->privacyStatus = $video_status;
        $status->setLicense($video_publish_license);
        $status->setPublicStatsViewable($video_public_stats_viewable);

        //
        $recordingDetails=new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoRecordingDetails();

        $locationdetails=new Google_Service_YouTube_GeoPoint();
        $locationdetails->setLatitude($resource['geo_lat']);
        $locationdetails->setLongitude($resource['geo_long']);

        $recordingDetails->setLocation($locationdetails);


        // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
        $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
        $video->setSnippet($snippet);
        $video->setStatus($status);
        $video->setRecordingDetails($recordingDetails);

        // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
        // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
        // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
        if(!is_numeric($youtube_chunk_size)){$youtube_chunk_size=10;}

        $chunkSizeBytes = intval($youtube_chunk_size) * 1024 * 1024;

        // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
        // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
        $client->setDefer(true);

        // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
        $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet,recordingDetails", $video);

        // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $client,
            $insertRequest,
            'video/*',
            null,
            true,
            $chunkSizeBytes
        );
        $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


        // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
        $status = false;
        $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
          $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
          $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
        }

        fclose($handle);

        // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
        $client->setDefer(true);

        $youtube_new_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" . $status['id'];

        return array(true,$youtube_new_url);
      }
catch (Google_ServiceException $e)
    {
    $errortext= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }
catch (Google_Exception $e)
    {
    $errortext= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
   }
catch (Google_ServiceException $e)
    {
    $errortext = sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }
catch (Google_Exception $e)
    {
    $errortext = sprintf('<p>A client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }        

if(isset($errortext))
        {
        return array(false,$errortext);
        }
```

Comment: Decent question but try to include the relevant part of your code and format your post. You can use code by using backticks or by indenting it four spaces (alternatively select code to be indented and press ctrl + k). More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you set an "invalid" value on an object and from your details I understand is related to Google_Service_YouTube_VideoRecordingDetails or Google_Service_YouTube_GeoPoint. My guess is that you are setting coordinates in wrong format but is just a guess. Try comment this line `$recordingDetails->setLocation($locationdetails);` and check the result. I've experienced same kind of problem with google drive (if I uncomment line with createdTime i get ***Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message 'Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 400: global, Invalid value for: Invalid format: "1463431798" is malformed at "8")' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/gdrive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php:334***)

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->title = "repkit.tar.gz";
  // $file->createdTime = time();
```

So maybe Double is referring to some expected format and the only place I can guess are coordinates.
Hope this give you some clue.

Comment: It's been almost a year since my question was posted. I was able to get this working. Looking back at the code I do have a lot more checks for potential empty values. My guess is that I was attempting to to include empty values in `$locationdetails`.